# How to import key vault access policies?

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault, import-csv

Trying to import multiple access policies into multiple key vaults in a Azure subscription.

I was able to get an export and populate to CSV exactly what I needed.

Problem I am having is on the import-csv foreach-object. Because Key vault requires comma separated values on the permissions keys, secrets and certificate it will not work with my command as its looking for a single variable.

Example. -PermissionsToKeys All,Get,Update

My PowerShell command.

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\kv-policies.csv" | ForEach-Object {
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $_.KeyVaultName -UserPrincipalName $_.UPN -PermissionsToCertificates $_.PermissionsToCertificatesStr -PermissionsToKeys $_.PermissionsToKeysStr -PermissionsToSecrets $_.PermissionsToSecretsStr}
```

Error

Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'PermissionsToCertificates'. The argument "string
Substring(int startIndex), string Substring(int startIndex, int length)" does not belong to the set "all,get,list,delet
e,create,import,update,managecontacts,getissuers,listissuers,setissuers,deleteissuers,manageissuers,recover,purge,backu
p,restore" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command
again.
At line:2 char:112

- ... sionsToCertificates $_.PermissionsToCertificatesStr.Substring -Permis ...
- ```
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy], ParameterBindingValidationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.SetAzureKeyVaultAcces
    sPolicy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried testing your scenario but as we are doing for multiple users and multiple permissions it’s a limitation to use Powershell to update the access policy . So, its recommended to use ARM template to assign multiple policies.

If its multiple users and single permission then you can use your Powershell script .

**Step1:** For adding Multiple access policies for users you will need to get the objectID for the users present in azure ad .

You can use use the CLI command :

```
az ad user show --id "upn" --query "objectId"
```

**Step 2:** Then you can use the below Template to add multiple access policies to a Keyvault .

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "keyVaultName": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },

    "resources": [
     {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/add')]",
      "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
      "properties": {
      "accessPolicies": [
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                        "objectId": "UPN1ObjectID",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore",
                                "UnwrapKey",
                                "WrapKey"
                            ],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Set",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "certificates": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore",
                                "ManageContacts",
                                "ManageIssuers",
                                "GetIssuers",
                                "ListIssuers",
                                "SetIssuers",
                                "DeleteIssuers"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                        "objectId": "UPN2ObjectID",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Set",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "certificates": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Import",
                                "Update",
                                "Create"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                        "objectId": "UPN3ObjectID",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Set",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "certificates": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore",
                                "ManageContacts",
                                "ManageIssuers",
                                "GetIssuers",
                                "ListIssuers",
                                "SetIssuers",
                                "DeleteIssuers"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
       }
    ]
}
```

**Step 4:** Now **Connect-Azaccount** in Powershell and execute the template using below command.

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "keyvaultresourcegroup" -TemplateFile kvpolicies.json
```

It will ask you the keyvault Name and after providing it you will have successfully added the access policies to the Keyvault.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[Create an Azure key vault and a vault access policy by using ARM template | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vault-create-template?tabs=CLI#add-an-access-policy-to-a-key-vault-resource-manager-template)